# How to create formatted headings using a dash or star

Tags: linux, aix

I have headings that I would like to make stand out using dashes between the sentence. For example below:

---

### What Update statistics options do you want to perform on r3qa2shop10@r3dcqa2...

1) UPDATE STATISTICS for the ENTIRE DATABASE
2) UPDATE STATISTICS for a particular TABLE in a DATABASE. All columns are updated in this case.
3) UPDATE STATISTICS for a particular COLUMN of a particular TABLE in a DATABASE.
4) UPDATE STATISTICS for a PROCEDURE in a DATABASE.
5) UPDATE STATISTICS for a FUNCTION in a DATABASE.
6) UPDATE STATISTICS for a ROUTINE in a DATABASE.
7) UPDATE STATISTICS by setting your own RESOLUTION.

I am current using the below, which does work, but perhaps is there an easier way of doing what I want?

h1="What Update statistics options do you want to perform on $SERVER@$HOST..."

no=`printf "$h1" | tr -s ' ' | tr ' ' '_' | wc -m`

yes '-' | head -n "$no" | tr -d "\n";echo

echo $h1

yes '-' | head -n "$no" | tr -d "\n";echo

I am working on a AIX system, but should not be a problem with linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is short enough:

```
h1="What Update statistics options do you want to perform on $SERVER@$HOST..."
line=$(echo "$h1" | sed 's/./-/g')
printf "%s\n%s\n%s\n" "$line" "$h1" "$line"
```